# Managing synchronous XHR/Ajax call in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have a product built in angularJS , and I have created almost 300 controllers. All the contollers have a XHR call (not $http call, it is basic javascript XMLHttpRequest ) for checking session data (by calling a service at the beginning of the controller). At the starting time I made a mistake by creating it in synchronous way (synchronous call is defined in the service), now it is deprecated in mozilla firefox and will deprecate in chrome soon. Is there have a alternative way to make synchronous XHR calls without changing all the controllers into a $watch ?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'path/to/my/APIservice', false);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there a reason you want the calls to be synchronous? The reason they're deprecated is that they block the UI, which makes for a terrible user experience. I would suggest figuring out how to make them asynchronous (trivial, but a separate question).

Comment: First of all thanks for your kind attention, Actually all the codes in controllers should run only after reaching that session data from the APIs, So I have to make the controller wait till it reaches back in my $rootScope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @**Tom Jenkins** for your kind reply,
I have found solution for this.

I have created a new state and routed to that from all the other states to  and then will load the XHR call asynchronously from the newly created state/controller and after getting the response I used to redirect the state to the previous one with the data loaded.

I don't know if this is the actual solution or not, but it saved my time from editing all the 300 js files. :)

> Eg:
>
> I am refreshing the **home** state, but it needs some session data to
>   be loaded from database to show the page. Then I redirect the state to
>   **checkSession** state and in that controller I call the service and in the promise of that call I stores the data to $rootScope and then
>   using $state.go() I redirect the state to **home** again.